# While running an R Kernel in a Google Colab notebook, how can a data frame be exported as a .csv file?

Tags: r, export-to-csv, google-colaboratory

The title of the question pretty much says it all. I’m using R in Google Colab and while analyzing some data I have generated an output data frame which I wish to export (either to Google Drive or to my local desktop). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you looking for a code snippet within the `R` runtime? I remember exporting something withing the UI a few weeks ago. If you're fine with a manual solution I can probably find something

Comment: @anddt Every solution is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can save a `.csv` file in Colab  root folder with a classic:

```
write.csv(your_df, file='output.csv')
```

You will find the file in the left sidebar, clicking on it will pop the option to download it.
[image]

Comment: Any idea what I have to do when I want to export it directly to my mounted drive folder?