# How to export a csv file using r in colab?

Tags: r

Using rstudio and the googledrive package on colab, how do I export a csv object to a google drive folder? I have spent the last three days trying without success. A similar question was asked here

[While running an R Kernel in a Google Colab notebook, how can a data frame be exported as a .csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64246944/while-running-an-r-kernel-in-a-google-colab-notebook-how-can-a-data-frame-be-ex)

in 2021 but the csv file does NOT show up in the sidebar file list as it did then. In the meantime, has anyone found a real solution or at least a work-around that works? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't reproduce - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kx4AK.png . Did you refresh file list?